# How to prove that $x^2≡2(\bmod 3)$ is not a complete square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Let $m$ be the product of first n primes (n > 1) , in the following expression :

$$m=2⋅3…p_n$$

I want to prove that $(m-1)$ is not a complete square.

I found two ways that might prove this . My problem is with the SECOND way .

**First solution (seems to be working) :**

The first way that I used is this :

Proof by negation : assume that $m-1$ is a complete square , i.e. $m-1 = x^2$ , then

$m=x^2+1=x^2-(-1)=(x-(-1))(x+(-1))=(x+1)(x-1)$

So we have either :

1. $(x+1)$ is even and $(x-1)$ is even
2. $(x+1)$ is even and $(x-1)$ is odd
3. $(x-1)$ is even and $(x+1)$ is odd

First case :  $(x+1)$ is even and $(x-1)$ is even  , then $m$ looks like this :

$m=2⋅otherNumbersA⋅2⋅otherNumbersB$

If we disregard $2$ then $m$ is a multiplication of $n-1$ prime numbers , then

$m$ is a multiplication of : $2 \cdot bigPrimeNumber$ . Contradiction .

The other two cases are just the same .

**Second solution (my problem) :**

What I'm interested in is the following solution (that I'm stuck in) :

Proof by negation : assume that : $m-1 = x^2$ and $m=2⋅3…p_n$ , means that $m$ divides by 3 , so we can write : $m-1≡2(mod 3)$ , which means that :

$m-1≡2(mod 3) ===> (m-1)-2=3q  , q\in N ===> m-3=3q=m=3(1+q)$

Meaning :

$m-1=x^2$

$m-1≡2(mod 3)$

$x^2≡2(mod 3)$

How do I continue from here ? how can I use : $x^2≡2(mod 3)$ to reach a contradiction ?

Thanks

Comment: Your first attempt is wrong from the start, because $x^2-(-1) \ne (x-(-1))(x+(-1))$.

Comment: Your first solution suggests that $x^2+1=(x+1)(x-1)$, which is wrong!!!

Comment: @barak manos: Thanks , I already got that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any integer $\displaystyle x, x\equiv0, 1,2\pmod3$

$\displaystyle\implies x^2\equiv0,1^2\equiv1,2^2\equiv1\pmod3$

Comment: I don't understand your solution , can please give some more details ?

Comment: @ron, Any integer can be written as $3c,3c+1,3c+2$ right?  Now square each of  them and find the remainder in each case

Answer (score 1):

The follow-on to the previous answer is that since $x^2 \equiv 2 \mod 3$ has no solution,
and $m-1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$, there cannot be a number $x$ such that $m-1 = x^2$.

It is worth pointing out that the first "solution" given is completely bogus because it contains a mistake in the first equation, which ends up reading $[x^2 + 1 ]= m = (x+1)(x-1) [= x^2 - 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

All squares modulo $3$ are: $\{0,1\} $.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a solution to $x^2 \equiv  2$ (mod $3$), then $x$ must be $0$, $1$ or $2$ (mod $3$). Now you can try each case and see that none of these will give you a solution:

- If $x \equiv 1,2$ (mod $3$) then $x^2 \equiv$ $1$ (mod $3$)
- If $x \equiv 0$ (mod $3$) then $x^2 \equiv$ $0$ (mod $3$)

So in none of these cases do we have $x^2 \equiv  2$ (mod $3$)

Answer (score 0):

IT IS CLEAR THAT ONE CAN WRITE ANY INTEGER IN THE FORM OF - 3K OR 3K+1 OR 3K+2 AS 0,1,2 ARE THE RESIDUES SET FOR 3. THUS WHEN WE SQUARE IT AND DIVIDE THE EXPRESSION BY 3- WE GET ONLY 0 AND 1 AS THE REMAINDER- IE;- FOR 3K IT IS OBVIOUSLY 0, FOR THE OTHER TWO IT IS 1. THUS WE CAN NEVER WRITE IT AS X^2 CONGRUENT TO 2 ( MOD 3)